# Entity Framework table per concrete type issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 7 with TPC (table per concrete type) inheritance and trying to figure out the following scenario:

I have an entity called **Ad**. This class is base and abstract. The derived classes from **Ad** are: CarAd, MotorAd, etc... Using TPC I'm able to create separate tables from my derived entity classes and having EF not creating a table for my base class (which is correct behaviour). So far so good. I also have an entity called Setting which has foreign key to my base **Ad** entity.
This relationship between **Ad** and **Setting** breaks my table-per-concrete type structure and EF creates a table only for **Ad** entity by combining all properties from the derived classes and therefore there are many nullable columns - and TPH (table per hierarchy) inheritance occurs - not my desired result. How can I change my structure to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: How should an foreign key work pointing to 2 different tables? It seams Table per type would be the better choice.

Comment: @Mikey You're right, but an ugly solution would be to have in my Setting class two foreign keys, each for CarAd and MotorAd....

Comment: Thats why, i suggest Table per Type (TPT not TPC), you then have a table  for Ad, containing Id only (for now), but fewer nullable columns ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mikey, I get your point here, I've tried that also and couldn't get it working but it turned out that TPT is not implemented in Entity Framework 7 yet, so TPH is the only option available for now.